# Best way to set desired range with inverse trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, modulo, periodic

I am currently performing some inverse trigonometric operations.  The actual formula I am using is at the bottom of this post, but is not super important.  Minimally, I am taking an arctangent `atan2(x,y)` result in `[-π,π)`.  However, for reasons, I need the "equivalent" result on `[0,2π)`, i.e. where `-π` maps to `π` and `-π/2` maps to `3π/2`, etc.  I can achieve this by taking the sign of the result, and if it is negative adding `2π`:

```
function fix_range(angle float) float :=
    if angle < 0:
        angle += 2π
    return angle
```

...but I'd prefer to have a "math" solution to this.  Is there a convenient mathematical formulation to adjust periodic ranges into a desired range?  For example, is there a formula (without any logical control structures) so that:

```
function adjust_val(val float, min_range float, period float) := ?
```

So that `adjust_val(-π/2, 0, 2π)` gives `3π/2`?

Common "math" operations allowed, for example anything available to `numpy` or other math libraries in other languages.

#### Appendix:

Here's the formula I'm combatting with:

```
atan2(sin(lat_1)*sin(lon_1)*cos(lat_2)*cos(lon_2) - sin(lat_2)*sin(lon_1)*cos(lat_1) + sin(lon_2)*cos(lat_2)*cos(lon_1), sin(lat_1)*cos(lat_2)*cos(lon_1)*cos(lon_2) - sin(lat_2)*cos(lat_1)*cos(lon_1) - sin(lon_1)*sin(lon_2)*cos(lat_2)) - pi
```

Comment: isn't this just a modulo? Like you could do `mod(some_value+2pi,2pi)` to get it back around to [0,2pi)?